# Parallel and ls with white spaces

Tags: gnu-parallel

This command works fine for dir with "regular" names as dir1 mydir my-dir, etc

```
ls | parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
```

give me the number of files for each dir

but for dir with white spaces like "my dir" or my long dir name don't work and give error.

How to quote/escape the white spaces?

Comment: You can start by not parsing the output of `ls` and using another tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to list the number of regular files in the sub-directories from where you execute your cmd, here is a one-liner that will do that for you:

```
 $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -print0 2>/dev/null \
   | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "%20s:  %d\n" "{}" "$(find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f 2>/dev/null| wc -l)"'
```

Example output:

```
              ./Maildir:  0
             ./.dvisvgm:  0
               ./.pyenv:  5
             ./.ipython:  0
   ./.ipynb_checkpoints:  3
                ./.tmux:  1
         ./.virtualenvs:  12
         ./seaborn-data:  2
               ./.local:  2
                ./bgpix:  12
                 ./.vim:  7
     ...
```

- I added `2>/dev/null` in each `find` block only to avoid some unwanted file access issues on the platform I used to run tests.  You may do away with it if you foresee no such file permission issues when stat'ing your files as part of your `find` cmds.
- I also suppress all output concerning `$PWD` (your present working directory, denoted `.`) in keeping with my assumption stated above, which was that you are only interested in counting *regular* files in current 1st-level subdirectories.
- to count regular files in your whole sub-directory tree, starting at `$PWD`, just omit the `-maxdepth 1` global option in the first `find` block above (but keep it in the 2nd one).

To better highlight the similarity with the solution relying on `parallel` (below), the above can be rewritten:

```
$ xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "%20s:  %d\n" "{}" "$(find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f 2>/dev/null| wc -l)"' \
  < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

Relying on `parallel` instead of `xargs`, as in the above, requires escaping some quotes as follows (output is exactly as before):

```
$ parallel -0 -I {} \
  'sh -c "printf \"%20s: %d\n\" \"{}\" \"$(find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f 2>/dev/null | wc -l)\""' \
  :::: < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

- `xargs` and `parallel` use the same two arguments `-0 -I {}` ,
- the shell command to execute is the Bourne shell between single quotes, 
  `'sh -c "printf ..."'`, and
- the input to parallelize, introduced by `::::`, is the process substitution input file `<(...)` which contains the output of the "find all subdirectories at first sublevel starting at `$PWD`" cmd.

Answer (score 3):

GNU Parallel has no problems dealing with spaces:

```
$ mkdir 'a  b'
$ touch 'a  b/c  d'
$ ls | parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
a  b 1
```

It requires `-0`, if the names contain \n:

```
$ mkdir 'a

b'
$ touch 'a

b/c

d'
# fails
$ ls | parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
$ parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l' ::: *
# works
$ printf "%s\0" * | parallel -0 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
$ parallel -0 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l' ::: *
```

So what you see is probably due to your `ls` doing something weird: It may be an alias to `ls --some-weird-option`. Try `\ls` instead (or use `printf ... | ... -0` or `-0 ... ::: *` as show above):

```
\ls | parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
```

(PS: Are you aware of `--tag`:

```
parallel --tag 'ls {}|wc -l' ::: *
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Without the complications of `parallel`, `xargs`, or passing pathnames back and forth:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for dir in */; do
    set -- "$dir"/*
    printf '%s:\t%s\n' "${dir%/}" "$#"
done
```

That is, iterate over all directories and count the number of names that the `*` glob expands to in each.

The above is for `bash`, and we set the `nullglob` shell option to ensure that non-matching patterns are removed instead of retained unexpanded.  I'm also setting the `dotglob` shell option to be able to match hidden names.

The `zsh` shell can do it while at the same time filtering the glob matches for only directories (for the loop) and only, e.g., regular files (for the loop body).  In the code below, the glob qualifier `(ND/)` makes the preceding `*` only match directories, with the same effect as with `nullglob` and `dotglob` set in the `bash` shell, and `(ND.)` makes the preceding `*` only match regular files in the same way.

```bsh
for dir in *(ND/); do
    set -- $dir/*(ND.)
    printf '%s:\t%s\n' $dir $#
done
```

Would you want to do this *recursively*, to get the count of names in each directory in a hierarchy, then you could just plug in the above in `find`:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
    for dir do
        set -- "$dir"/*
        printf "%s:\t%s\n" "$dir" "$#"
    done' bash {} +
```

(the above is a bit different from the plain `bash` loop at the start of this answer as this would never count names in directories accessed via symbolic links), or,

```bsh
find . -type d -exec zsh -c '
    for dir do
        set -- $dir/*(ND.)
        printf "%s:\t%s\n" $dir $#
    done' zsh {} +
```

Comment: See also `for dir (*(ND/)) () { printf '%s:\t%s\n' $dir $#; } $dir/*(ND.oN)` which avoid clobbering the positional parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround found using find instead of ls.

```
find * -type d -maxdepth 0 | parallel 'echo -n {}" "; ls {}|wc -l'
```

Comment: Hi @elbarna ! Careful with using global options such as `-maxdepth 0`after stat options such as the argument `-type d`. Orders matters here and global options always come first in `find`.  Also maybe my solution is not what you are looking for... Apparently you want to count **files AND sub-directories** ONLY in your **non-hidden sub-directories** ? At least it is what this solution does. Finally favor `printf` over `echo`whenever you can for all these [reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/72707).